# Volume bounded by $y^2+z^2=x$ and $x=y$

Tags: calculus, volume, surface-integrals

I need general help in solving for the area bounded by 
$y^2+z^2=x$ and $x=y,\ z=0$.

I'm trying to get the limits of integration for
$\int \int \int dzdxdy $. Here's my attempt so far:

$0\leq z\leq \sqrt {x-y^2}$

$ \sqrt {x} \leq y\leq x$

$ 0 \leq x\leq 1$

$\int_{1}^{0}\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{x} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{x-y^2}} dzdydx=S$

But I can't solve this integral.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
V&=\int_{x=0}^{x=1}\int_{y=x}^{y=\sqrt{x}}\int_{z=0}^{z=\sqrt{x-y^2}}\mathrm dx\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x\\
&=\int_{x=0}^{x=1}\int_{y=x}^{y=\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{x-y^2}\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x
\end{align*}
Now, in order to integrate this we can use a $\color{blue}{\text{trigonometric sustitution}}$ by setting $y=\sqrt{x}\sin t$, $\mathrm d y=\sqrt{x}\cos t\,\mathrm dt$, then
\begin{align*}
\int\sqrt{x-y^2}\,\mathrm d y&=\int \sqrt{x-x\sin^2 t}\sqrt{x}\cos t\,\mathrm dt\\
&=\int x\cos^2 t\,\mathrm d t\\
&=x\left(\frac{t}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\sin 2t\right)+C\\
&=x\left(\frac{t}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sin t\cos t\right)+C\\
&=\frac{x}{2}\left(\sin^{-1}\frac{y}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{y\sqrt{x-y^2}}{x}\right)+C\\
\int_{y=x}^{y=\sqrt{x}}\sqrt{x-y^2}\,\mathrm d y&=\frac{\pi}{4}x-\frac{1}{2}x\sin^{-1}\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{x-x^2}
\end{align*}

It follows
\begin{align*}
V&=\int_0^1\left(\frac{\pi}{4}x-\frac{1}{2}x\sin^{-1}\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{x-x^2}\right)\,\mathrm d x
\end{align*}